# Can I install a handlebar brake handle without removing the grips?

Tags: brakes, handlebars, cruiser

I recently bought a cruiser bike with coaster brakes. I decided I wasn't happy with the stopping power, so I want to add a hand brake to the front wheel.

I ordered some parts online, but I have run into some trouble with installing the brake handle. It doesn't open wide enough to attach at any point to the handlebars, it appears that I have to take off the handlebar grips and slide it onto the handlebars.

But it's a new bike with new leather handlebar grips that I'd rather not ruin. I've seen some videos online about removing grips with Pledge and a screw driver, but that seems kind of iffy to me.

Do they make a handlebar grips that attach similar to some phone mounts that I've seen, where they open up wide and then screw shut?

Comment: Leather grips are probably glued on, whereas most bike grips are rubbery/plastic that holds itself in place without an adhesive.  Removing leather could require un-stitching too.

Comment: I have several bikes equipped with leather grips; mine are not glued on. I have excellent luck removing grips (without damaging them) using air from my air compressor. I pull up just a bit at one point to insert the tip of my air blower nozzle and twist and pull whilst blasting air under the grip, works great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many BMX levers are hinged, so they don't require messing with the grip. These can be had for either short pull (canti/caliper/u-brake) or long pull (v-brake/mechanical disc), so make sure to get the right pull. They're intended for one or two finger use.

[image: hinged mx lever]

Various basic "touring" levers, of the stamped sheet metal variety, also go on and off without removing the grip. Some, as in the currently made/available Sunlite one pictured below, have little clampy bits that detach and then are slid back into place, and others have a steel band clamp you can open up to bend around. These generally aren't the nicest brake levers, but they work and may match the aesthetic of the bike better.

[image: junky touring lever]

FWIW, most nicer modern hydro levers have either a hinge, faceplate, or other scheme to allow this as well.

[image: M7000]
[image: Elixir R]